# Firebase hosting

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting, gtmetrix

When testing the speed of our site hosted on Firebase hosting, we're seeing this recommendation from GTmetrix:

```
IMPACT  AUDIT       
High    
Enable Keep-Alive
1 request found.    
Enabling HTTP Keep-Alive or HTTP persistent connections allow the same TCP connection to send and receive multiple HTTP requests, thus reducing the latency for subsequent requests.

Learn how to improve this
URL WITHOUT KEEP-ALIVE ENABLED
https://SOME_URL.com
```

Firebase hosting docs are silent on the http keep-alive setting. Anyone knows how to set it up?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You might want to avoid Keep-Alive since it's [prohibited in HTTP/2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Keep-Alive).

Comment: Interesting, thanks, I wonder why such a big site as GTmetrix would still be recommending keep-alive as a high-impact measure it to improve page performance. Could it be that the general header is still ok: The Connection general header controls whether or not the network connection stays open after the current transaction finishes... on that page you sent